# Allow only wrapper script but not command

Tags: permissions, scripting, resources

Say one has a resource hungry command that users on a server need to run. I want to wrap said command with a wrapper script that will parse the arguments passed and ensure that the command is only being used under certain conditions or times.

The problem is that if the program itself is not executable the wrapper won't be able to run it either. I'd also like the command not to run as root.

Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm not sure what you mean by not wanting the command to be executed as root, though.  I was assuming you were asking about `sudo` configuration.  How do you plan to limit permissions to the executable in the first place?

Comment: @Wildcard - I'm not sure. I was thinking of somehow turning off executable permissions for all users, and then perhaps running the script through a group that does, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: i dont get it - if the program is not executable, then how would it be run with any number of arguments under any condition? i mean - how do you usually run it?

Comment: @mikeserv right now all users have exec permissions. I want them to only be able to run the command under certain conditions that will be determined by my wrapper

Comment: well, if it is a wrapper that determines it, then just do that thing you said with groups. user/group *nobody* is often used like that. read your wrapper on a shell's stdin - save no input history. put the execution code in a function: `ok(){ your_program; }`, the condition checks in another. if the checks turn out do nothing, if not redefine the execution function: `ok(){ exec <&- </dev/null; }` and call `ok` at the tail end of the checks regardless.

Comment: @mikeserv, that is a fairly misleading comment.  I'll post an answer below.

Comment: @Wildcard - what'd i get wrong? maybe i dont understand?

Comment: @mikeserv, finished my answer.  I don't understand your comment solution fully but what I was referring to was the fact that it's not secure at all and doesn't *prevent* anyone from running the command directly; see the bolded parts of my answer.  Could be that this is fine for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @Wildcard - well... kind of. but the difference between an fd and a file is a big deal. with commands like `ulimit`, `newgroup` and `runuser` and an ephemeral set of commands that evaporate or morph to something else under the right  conditions when the source file has already been unlinked or when input is read on a self-pipe can make it a lot more than difficult to beat it. a parent process can call `newgroup <command_script` for example, and the parent is the one that needs permissions to read it, not the child that runs it.

Comment: @mikeserv could you add an answer detailing your group trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: **It is not possible to *force* your users to use your wrapper script.**

The reason for this is fairly simple; a shell script is an *interpreted* program.  That means that `bash` (or some other shell process) must *read* the file in order to run the commands that are called in it.

This in turn means that a user who has permission to run the wrapper script, must have permission to do everything that is done in the wrapper script.  In the vast majority of cases*, a shell script, even one with lots of internal logic and conditionals, does exactly the same thing when you run it as it would if you typed the entire script into your command prompt, line by line.

**If you are merely trying to make it difficult for uneducated users to slow down your system, there are a multitude of ways of doing this**, such as what @mikeserv suggests in a comment on your question.  I can think of at least five more ways offhand**, many of which could be used in combination; the crucial thing to understand about these is that *they're not secure*.  They don't actually *prevent* the user from using the command directly instead of the wrapper script, and they also don't (and can't) prevent the user from making his own copy of the wrapper script (which he must have read permissions on to be able to run at all) and modifying it however he likes.

It *is* possible to write a short C program to perform the function of your wrapper script, which compiles to a binary executable, and then make that C program SUID*** so it is the only way the user can run the command you are talking about, but that's beyond my scope and area of expertise.

Other options involve extremely odd workarounds (hacks) like setting a cronjob to modify your sudoers file to allow permissions to run the command only during specific times of day...but that's getting really, really weird and Bad Idea territory.

---

I think the standard way to accomplish this (although still without *forcing* tech-savvy users to use your wrapper script) would be:

(I'll pretend the command to restrict is `date`.)

1. Ensure that inside your script, its call to `date` uses the absolute path: `/bin/date`  (You can find out what this is by running `which date`.)  Also ensure your script has a proper shebang, so that it can be run without needing to type `bash ./myscript` but can just be run as `./myscript`, and ensure it is readable and executable by everyone.  (`chmod 555 myscript`)
2. Put your wrapper script in `/usr/local/bin/` and rename it as `date`.
3. Check that users have `/usr/local/bin` at the *start* of their `$PATH` variable.  (Just log in as a user and run `echo "$PATH"`.)  They should already have this by default.  It doesn't have to be at the very start as long as it's in their path before `/bin` (or whatever the location of the original `date` command is).

If they don't have it in their path, you can add it by running: `echo 'PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/my_path_prefix.sh`

Now any time a user tries to run the command directly, he will actually be running your wrapper script, because the directory where your wrapper script is appears first in his `$PATH`.

---

A much more hack-y "blackhat" sort of a solution would be to actually mask the original binary, not by putting another version earlier in the path for users, but by putting the wrapper script in place of the command itself, in its original location.  Use at your own risk:

1. Put the command itself somewhere outside the normal `bin` directories so no one has it in their path.  You could move it to, for example, `/var/local`.  (There may be a better place, but this is a hack already, so it doesn't matter much, does it?)
2. Ensure that the call to the `date` within your wrapper script points to the *new* location for `date`—its absolute path: `/var/local/date` in my example.
3. Move your wrapper script into `date`'s old location, with `date`'s original name.

The main caveat is that **every time *anyone* tries to run that command, including system init scripts, they will get your wrapper script instead.**

This is purely a hack and would not qualify as *good* system administration.  But it *is* possible and you may as well know that it could be done.  The better solution is what I posted above.

---

<sub>*The exceptions to this have to do with modifying the environment and programs that behave differently when they are run interactively vs. when they are run from a script.  These exceptions have nothing to do with *permissions*, though, so they're not relevant to this discussion.</sub>

<sub>**Ask about them in the comments if you are interested and I'll expand on them.</sub>

<sub>***NOT suid root.  If you do this, just create a user, put him in a group which is the only one with permission to run the command you are talking about (`chmod 010` or something) and then `chown` your fresh-compiled wrapper binary to be owned by that user and set its suid bit with `chmod 4511`.</sub>

Comment: What makes a C code program different from a script?

Comment: @nbubis, because executing a compiled C program only depends upon having execute permission, not read permission, and because the `suid` bit cannot apply to scripts.  This is how it is possible for some binary executables (such as compiled C programs) to do things that the user running them does *not* have permission to do, such as change the `/etc/passwd` file by running `passwd`—such binaries have the `suid` bit set to make this possible.

Comment: @nbubis, by the way, a "binary" or "binary file" just means that the contents of the file is not just text.  It might even *include* text, like a Microsoft Word document, but it's not *just* text in the file.  (A `.doc` has a lot of formatting information.)  An executable binary such as a C program only has meaning to the computer; it's instructions for the computer to execute rather than text for a human to read.  C programs are *compiled*, that is, turned into machine instructions for the computer, *from* C source code which is written by humans and read by humans.  Does that help?  :)

Comment: Can't I get the same effect by just adding `ALL HOST command` to/etc/sudoers?

Comment: @nbubis I thought you didn't want the command to run as root?  If you don't mind having the command run as root, then sure, add it to sudoers.  But how does that help with your wrapper script conditional checks?

Comment: Exactly. But won't a C script also run the program as root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33676/discussion-between-wildcard-and-nbubis).